# AWS Api Gateway Documentation - cant create schema

Tags: aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Today i got into swagger and swagger-ui to create the documentation of our API.

We are using AWS API Gateway with a Lambda function, since AWS is comming with an in-built option for documentation we are going with it.

Sadly, I am pretty limited with this option or I am doing it wrong.

As an example

```
responses:
 '200':
   description: 200 response
   schema:
     $ref: '#/definitions/Empty'
```

I can´t create an alternative schema, nor im able to edit the existing `/Empty` schema.

Is there a solution for my problem?

For example

... to not use an schema and just write the whole response in there?

... to show me how to create an alternative schema?

**EDIT**

For me it seems like an AWS problem, not my swagger file in generall. If someone reads over this i added more informations.

It doesnt matter if i use "create Documetation Part" --> Type = Response (Body) or i go to Ressources --> Method which i want to set the Response (Body) --> Method Response and set the Respone Body to an Modell.

My Modell looks like this

```
{
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description" : "Example Promotion",
  "title" : "Promotion",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "Status" : { "type" : "string"}
  }
 }
}
```

It gives me no error, but if i go to "Publish Documentation" it seems to no put the Respone (Body) i set into the swagger.json on the Method Response part, nor on the Defenitions at the end of the file and set the schema path right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it easier to not use $ref when I was starting out.  After you have the knack how to write requests or response definitions, you can easily transition to referencing schemas using $ref.

What comes after schema statement?  That depends on what you expect to be returned -- text, an array, a JSON object, or an array of JSON objects, etc.  Typically it's the later two.  So here is an example of each.

```
schema:
  type: object
  description: This is a JSON object
  properties:
    fullName:
      type: string
    age:
      type: number
```

which defines: { fullName: "Jane Smith", age: 30 }

```
schema:
  type: array
  description: This is an array of JSON object
  items:
    type: object
    properties:
      carMake:
        type: string
      carModel:
        type: string
```

which defines: [{ carMake: "Ford", carModel: "Mustang" } ... ]

Clone github's swagger-ui onto your computer and run it as a local server.  Or you have free use of the [SwaggerHub](http://www.swaggerhub.com) if you don't mind the API definition to be public (or, after a trial period, pay for your APIs to be private).

The specification has changed over the years, so its important to know whether you are dealing with swagger v2 or openapi v3.  [www.swagger.io](http://www.swagger.io) has a good multi-page tutorial.  And you can find several public API examples at the SwaggerHub website.   I do not work for Smartbear, the originators of both the original swagger spec and swaggerhub tooling, but I've found them to be very helpful in the past.  Some of their staff monitor this website and answer questions.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for the response, generally your guide was right and helpfull, but my problem still exist. I Guess its an AWS Problem and not genreally a swagger problem. I Edit my Question a bit if you want to take a deeper look.

Comment: Oh ... I use S3, not API Gateway.  Does your API Gateway have CORS enabled?  I had to do that with my S3 bucket.